# Cars hitting end of screen and moving back

Tags: c#, winforms, 2d, picturebox

If I didn't make a title that correctly describes this I'm sorry as I struggled a lot with the title of this question. I am making a clone of Crossy Road(not to sell). My game has 2D graphics and is from a bird's eye perspective. Anyway my problem is that I need to move the cars back to the start after they hit the end of the screen and with a randomized car image. My game is in Winforms so the cars are picture boxes. I have searched around quite a bit but found nothing that explains nigh exactly what i need to do, as that is what i need. All answers please be direct and explain things thoroughly, i don't know a lot of c#. I am somewhat of a beginner.
Here is my Load(The 6 and 65 are guesses)

```
private void Frogger_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
timer1.Enabled = true;
Car1Hitbox = new Rectangle(x1, y1, 6, 65);
Car2Hitbox = new Rectangle(x2, y2, 6, 65);
Car3Hitbox = new Rectangle(x3, y3, 6, 65);
Car4Hitbox = new Rectangle(x4, y4, 6, 65);
Car5Hitbox = new Rectangle(x5, y5, 6, 65);
}
```

Here is my Timer

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.SuspendLayout();
Car1.Location = new Point(Car1.Location.X + 19, Car1.Location.Y);
x1 += 19;
Car2.Location = new Point(Car2.Location.X + 30, Car2.Location.Y);
x2 += 30;
Car3.Location = new Point(Car3.Location.X + 16, Car3.Location.Y);
x3 += 16;
Car4.Location = new Point(Car4.Location.X + 18, Car4.Location.Y);
x4 += 18;
Car5.Location = new Point(Car5.Location.X + 25, Car5.Location.Y);
x5 += 25;
this.ResumeLayout();
{
```

My cars are moving horizontally across the screen. My screen size is 642 by 654. Any and all help is appreciated.

Thank you for your time reading this.

Comment: Maybe you can add a `modulo` on the parameter `X` of the new `Location`, but this won't help you detecting when to change the car's appearance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a very good question for this site, but since I'm waiting for some lazy DBAs for some stuff, I'll bite.

There's a lot of things that could be improved with your code, but to address your specific question, you want to determine when you need to "recycle" each car. To do this, when you move, say, `Car1`, check if it is at (or beyond) the edge of your screen by adding the box's width to its current location. If that value is greater than or equal to your screen width, you reset the car (set the `x` component of the point to 0):

```
if(Car1.Location.X + Car1.Size.Width >= this.Width) {
  Car1.Location = new Point(0, Car1.Location.Y);
}
```

Really this whole thing would be made much easier if you kept all your cars in a `List<PictureBox>` and iterated through the list each time your timer ticked.